# Cmd+Tab not working on iOS 17

Tags: ios, keyboard, shortcut

When using an external Bluetooth keyboard (Logitech MX Keys Mini) with my iPhone (15 Pro Max running the latest iOS 17), I am unable to use the app switcher with the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcut.  Nothing happens.  Other keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for Home work fine, and the keyboard is definitely in Mac mode not PC mode so I can be sure <kbd>Cmd</kbd> is mapping and not being used as <kbd>Opt</kbd>, etc.

If I turn on the full keyboard access in Accessibility I am able to define various keyboard shortcuts, including one for the App Switcher.  If I manually set this to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it works fine, but obviously I have all the other things that go with using full keyboard access like having elements highlighted, etc, as well as switching on dozens of other shortcuts that I am not interested in using.

So I can rule in the keyboard working correctly, and the keys being mapped correctly, but am not able to access the app switcher via keyboard unless I specifically map it via Accessibility workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings, go to **Accessibility > Keyboards > Full Keyboard Access > Commands**

You will see the App Switcher shortcut has changed to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on the MX Mini does something else, so this will now only work if set to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

While you’re there, change “Touch” under the gestures section to “Enter”.

Hope this helps!